# How to unit test numerical computation for "no precision error"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, double, precision

We have a large system written in Java where precision, for most of the time, is not that important. We therefore store all numbers in double.

However, several years later new requirement emerged and for certain rare scenarios precision matters a great deal. So I am having this situation where I need to **take a price (represented in `double`), a base (also represented in `double`), and round the price to the nearest multiple of that base, and store the result, again, in `double`.**

In decimal form this is trivial:`result = roundDownToBase(price + base*0.5, base)`

I understand that carrying out the above formula naively with double will result in precision issue. I also understand a proper fix is to convert everything into BigDecimal during the calculation.

My question is, how can I systematically (unit) test that the BigDecimal version does not have the same precision issue that double version has? I can randomly choose a few values and assert the results, but that does not seem to give me too much confidence given the universe of inputs is infinite. Or, is there a way to systematically pick a few representative values in unit tests, and yield a reasonably high confidence of the code quality?

P.S. my code:

```
    public static double roundToNear(double price, double base) {
        BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(price);
        BigDecimal baseValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(base);
        BigDecimal two = BigDecimal.valueOf(2);
        BigDecimal halfUp = value.add(baseValue.divide(two));
        return roundDownToBase(halfUp.doubleValue(), base);
    }

    public static double roundDownToBase(double value, double base) {
        BigDecimal val1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        BigDecimal val2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(base);
        BigDecimal remainder = val1.remainder(val2);
        return MathUtil.isZeroOrNaN(remainder.doubleValue()) ? value:val1.subtract(remainder).doubleValue();
    }
```

Comment: You potentially lose precision when you convert `halfUp` to double.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes that is true if you just look at that single statement. however, the resulted imprecise double is still the double that best represents the true decimal halfup - e.g. the toString on that double will the be same as toString on the decimal. The thing here is that the roundDown method will take the double represented halfup into BigDecimal again, which will bring back the precision. BigDecimal.valueOf(halfup.doubleValue()) should be the same as halfup

Comment: "the toString on that double will the be same as toString on the decimal" Simple counterexample: Try `price=1e20` and `base=1`. The `halfUp" toString is 100000000000000000000.5, the double's toString is 1.0E20. Converting the double back to BigDecimal will get 1e20, without the extra 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this instance you can't test these methods as they are platform method, in my experience unit testing is for a code you have written, for instance if you think that roundDownToBase(10.01, 10.02) should return for instance 5 then that wouuld be a valid test otherwise you can't test Double as this is platform function

Comment: But even for my case, is it sufficient or common to randomly pick a few input pairs and assert the results? Is there a more systematic way to do it? For numerical computation algorithms how do we unit test them?

Comment: if you have a function addtwointeger(int a, and int b ){ return a+b;} the only test you can do is assertthat(addtwointeger(1,1)).isequalto(2); the arithmetic operation isn't in your control as such you can't test it, that is framework . I hope it makes sense.

Comment: What I mean is, when you treat your addTwoInteger as a black box where you have no idea it internally does a primitive add operation or some funny stuff such as for(int i=1; i<=b; i++) a = a+1; how do you write a test that you are  confident that your method does not screw up too much ?

Comment: in that case 100+300 wouldn't be equal to 400. so your test would fail